# Вопрос про ссылочные типы данных

Tags: c#

Если `string` является ссылочным типом, как и `class`, то почему у `str1` и `str2` разные значения? По идее обе переменных должны ссылаться на одну и ту же область памяти в куче, как `country1` и `country2`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Country country1 = new Country();
    country1.x = 1;
    country1.y = 2;

    Console.WriteLine("Country1 {0}, {1}", country1.x, country1.y);

    Country country2 = new Country();
    country2 = country1;
    country1.x = 3;

    Console.WriteLine("Country1 {0}, {1}", country1.x, country1.y);
    Console.WriteLine("Country2 {0}, {1}", country2.x, country2.y);
    ///////////////////
    string str1;
    str1 = "123";

    Console.WriteLine("Str1 {0}", str1);

    string str2;
    str2 = str1;
    str1 = "1234";

    Console.WriteLine("Str1 {0}", str1);
    Console.WriteLine("Str2 {0}", str2);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код в виде кода, а не в виде скриншота

Comment: Потому что вы создали и записали в str1 новый объект

Comment: @Андрей, создается новый объект `country1` и ссылки на `x` и `y` записываются в стек, по ссылкам значения в куче. Потом мы присваиваем `country2` `country1`, то есть оба объекта ссылаются на одну и ту же область памяти => поменяв один объект, изменяем другой. Затем создаем `str1` и присваиваем `123`, создаем `str2` и присваиваем `str1`, раз `string` ссылочный тип, оба объекта должны ссылаться на одну и ту же область памяти и быть взаимоизменяемыми, чего не происходит. Я не понимаю почему, можно тут подробнее? Новый объект бы записался, если бы был тип значений, но тут ссылочный

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У переменной значимого типа значение хранится в самой переменной. У переменной ссылочного типа в переменной хранится ссылка на некоторую область памяти, в которой в свою очередь хранится значение. Теперь о типе `string`, переменная такого типа хранит ссылку, но нюанс состоит в том, что выделенная память, на которую это ссылка указывает является неизменяемой, поэтому каждый раз когда вы проводите какие либо манипуляции со строкой вы, фактически создаете новый объект в памяти. И такие манипуляции затронут, только, непосредственно, ту переменную которая подверглась изменениям. Давайте рассмотрим ваш пример.

```
string str1; //здесь вы создали переменную str1, но она еще ни на что не ссылается
str1 = "123"; //здесь в переменную str1 записывается адрес литерала "123"
string str2;
str2 = str1; //здесь мы записали в переменную str2, значение адреса литерала "123"
             //который сохранен в переменной str1
str1 = "1234"; //а вот сейчас мы пишем в str1 ссылку на совершенно другой литерал
               //а в str2 остается старое значение, так с этой переменной 
               //вы никаких манипуляций не проводили
```

Да, небольшое добавление. Если вы сделаете так:

```
string str1 = "1234";
string str2 = str1;
string str3 = str1;
```

все три переменный будут ссылаться на одну область памяти, но любое изменение, любой из них не затронет остальные две, а просто породит еще одну строку.

Подробней можно почитать, например:

1. [Строки, неизменяемость и персистентность.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ruericlippert/2011/08/08/653/)
2. [Типы значений и ссылочные типы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: +1, но неизменяемость строк в этом вопросе по идее роли не играет.

Comment: @VladD, если я правильно понял вопрос, как раз неизменяемость строк ТС и смутила, так как на первый взгляд они ведут себя как значимые типы.

Comment: Хм. Но ведь если string заменить на StringBuilder, будет то же самое: https://ideone.com/XZbiO6. То есть, _все_ объекты так себя ведут.

Comment: @VladD, фокус в этой строчке `sb1 = new StringBuilder("1234");` тут сразу видно, что есть НОВЫЙ объект. А вот в `string str1 = "1234";` это неочевидно, может быть он есть, может "1234" непосредственно записывается в `str1`?

Comment: Окей, в таком случае необычность строк заключается в контексте вопроса в наличии у них _литералов_? Потому что присваивание ссылки работает одинаково.

Comment: @VladD, неа :). Их "необычность" в том, что в "простейших" случаях они ведут себя как значимый тип. И это следствие как раз их неизменяемости. [Ideone](https://ideone.com/lgE2Jk)

Comment: @Mirdin в строчке `string str1 = "1234"` - '"1234"' - это не новый объект. Если строчкой ниже написать `string str2 = "1234"` - то обе str скорее всего будут ссылаться на один и тот же `"1234"`. Т.е. код работает именно так, как и ожидалось бы для ссылочного типа. "положить в str ссылку на "1234"". Просто топикастер почему-то  ожидал, что присвоение 1234 сработает как для value type :)

Comment: @PashaPash, то что `string str1 = "1234"`, это присваивание переменной новой ссылки, очевидно для вас, меня, ВладаД... Но для начинающего (а очевидно ТС именно такой) `string` ведет именно как ["значимый тип"](https://ideone.com/lgE2Jk) и что б понять, что это не так, понадобится практика, понадобиться "лазить под капот".

Comment: @Mirdin: Это потому, что начинающие приходят из C++, а там присвоение `std::string s; s = "123"` ведёт себя именно так: модифицирует объект `s`. В C# такого поведения нет нигде.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите, String действительно является ссылочным типом, но ведет он себя в CLR несколько специфично, чтобы походить на тип значения. Поскольку строка традиционно относится к "базовым" типам, таким как int, double, Array, то программист подсознательно ожидает от строки поведения не как ссылочного, а как значимого типа. Для обеспечения такого поведения, при присваивании переменной строкового типа нового **литерала** каждый раз создается новый объект, а переменной возвращается ссылка на этот новый объект.
Таким образом, строку

```
var someString = "Value";
```

Можно **воспринимать** как такой **псевдокод**

```
var someString = new String(Char[]{'V','a','l','u','e'});
```

**UPDATE**
Если объект типа string со значением "Value" уже существует, то CLR попытается не создавать новый объект, а вернет ссылку на уже существующий. Как вывод, string это ссылочный тип, который передает свое значение ни как объект, а как ссылка на объект.

Comment: @PashaPash Да, CLR старается вернуть ссылку на уже существующий объект. Хотя это не факт. И в этом специфика, не находите?  string1 = "1", string2 = "1", string1 = string2; string2 = "3", a string1 = "1"?  Это поведение значимого типа. Очевидно, что такой результат достижим только если литерал **создает** новый объект. Как я и написал в своем ответе. Однако, как вы указали, ссылка может прийти на существующий объект, если таковой найдется, и это так. Такое бывает со всеми ссылочными типами? Нет. А для строк это возможно. Это о специфике. В своем ответе я объяснил, как можно воспринимать строку

Comment: А за полным объяснением лучше обращаться к Рихтеру. У него там несколько десятков страниц посвящено строкам.

Comment: Вы воспринимаете литералы как какие-то "данные строки", которые нужно "обернуть в объект". На самом деле все гораздо проще. Литералы это полноценные объекты-строки, создаваемые компилятором/рантаймом. Литерал ничего не создает. Он и есть полноценный объект. Т.е. ваше восприятие искажается тем, что вы не воспринимаете литерал как объект, а считаете его какими-то сырыми данными, в стиле c++. Для которых CLR старается кэшировать объекты. На самом деле CLR использует готовые объекты-строки, интернированные компилятором. Т.е. в разных сборках в в одном приложении вы получите разные объекты для "1"

Comment: Т.е. вы видите сложный хитрый механизм там, где на самом деле его нет :) а по поводу моего первого коммента - ну не создатся при каждом присвоении строки новы объект. Даже в вашей интерпретации - стоит заменить на "при каждом присвоении литерала строке". Заметьте, я не призываю вас перечитать Рихтера, просто предлагаю исправить фразу, которая опровергается простым примером кода вида string a = b;

Comment: Я собственно и не утверждал никогда что при a = b для a будет создан новый объект, я всегда имел в виду при присваивании литерала :) Насчет Рихтера я упомянул к слову, просто потому что вспомнилось, без всяких призывов) Свой ответ я отредактировал

Comment: Ок, спасибо за фикс ответа :)

Answer (score -1):

здарвствуйте я вам попробую обьяснить более понятным языком. Предположим вы создали 4 переменных типа стринг а потом сделали следующее

```
string s1 = "qwer";
string s2 = "abcd";
string s3 = s1;
string s4 = s2;
```

теперь у вас в s1 указывает на ту часть памяти где записана строка s3 также заметьте что s3 не указывает на ссылку s1 а именно на место памяти тоесть если мы изменим значение s1 или s3 другое значение не изменится. Также и с s2,s4. Думаю что разумно и доступно обьяснил желаю удачи. Теперь раз уж вы все это знаете попробуйте подумать и сказать без написания кода и компиляции что будет если сделать так

```
s4 = s1;
s1 = "1456";
```

какое будет значение у s1,s2,s3,s4?

Comment: "какое будет значение у s1,s2,s3,s4?" - у кого вы спрашивате?

Comment: в первую очередь у того кто написал вопрос а вообще  простая задача чтобы доказать себе что все понял из выше сказанного пусть думают все кто не понимают прочитали внимательно написанное и попробуют найти ответ

Comment: ТС последний раз заходил в окт. 17-го и он врядли прочтёт ваш ответ. Ознакомтесь в справке [как дать хороший  ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Потом мы вместе поправим ваш ответ.